# Distance between irregular binary curves in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, binary

Is there an optimal way to measure the distance between irregular binary curves?. For instance, in the following image I want to measure the distance between the first and second binary curve and an white area below. I was thinking in use the mean and standard deviation after iterating all columns with a for loop but I don't really know how to implemente it properly. Below the second line there is a white area. What I am trying to do is to  measure the distance as soon as a white pixel is found in that area so that I could estimate the distance between the first and second curve against the first white pixel in the area.

[image]

Any suggestion or current implementation with tasks like this?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Measuring the distance? Use Hausdorff distance for example or mean distance, depends on your task. Or do you want to know HOW to measure distances at all? Or do you know what you want to measure and how you can do it but you want to compute it faster?

Comment: What I want is to measure pixels distance but knowing how to do it. I am not looking for a faster implementation. Could you provided an example of implementation or a way to achieve one?. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "pixels distance" ? You must understand that as it stands, your problem is not clearly defined.

Comment: give cv::distanceTransform a try